# Docker 1.12 certificate missing using daemon.json file

Tags: docker, configuration, x509certificate

I am running docker 1.12 on Ubuntu 16.04, I need to change the bip option, so I create a custom `/etc/docker/daemon.json` configuration file that looks like this:

```
root@simo:/etc/docker# cat daemon.json 
{
    "authorization-plugins": [],
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"],
    "dns-opts": [],
    "dns-search": [],
    "exec-opts": [],
    "exec-root": "",
    "storage-driver": "",
    "storage-opts": [],
    "labels": [],
    "live-restore": true,
    "log-driver": "",
    "log-opts": {},
    "mtu": 0,
    "pidfile": "",
    "graph": "",
    "cluster-store": "",
    "cluster-store-opts": {},
    "cluster-advertise": "",
    "max-concurrent-downloads": 3,
    "max-concurrent-uploads": 5,
    "debug": true,
    "hosts": [],
    "log-level": "",
    "tls": false,
    "tlsverify": false,
    "tlscacert": "",
    "tlscert": "",
    "tlskey": "",
    "swarm-default-advertise-addr": "",
    "api-cors-header": "",
    "selinux-enabled": false,
    "userns-remap": "",
    "group": "",
    "cgroup-parent": "",
    "default-ulimits": {},
    "ipv6": false,
    "iptables": false,
    "ip-forward": false,
    "ip-masq": false,
    "userland-proxy": false,
    "ip": "0.0.0.0",
    "bridge": "",
    "bip": "172.17.42.1/16",
    "fixed-cidr": "",
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "",
    "default-gateway": "",
    "default-gateway-v6": "",
    "icc": false,
    "raw-logs": false,
    "registry-mirrors": [],
    "insecure-registries": [],
    "disable-legacy-registry": false,
    "default-runtime": "runc",
    "oom-score-adjust": -500
}
```

Now, if I start the daemon it simply not work saying: 

`FATA[0000] Could not load X509 key pair (cert: "", key: ""): open : no such file or directory`

Which is definitely correct, but doesn't let me use docker at all.

If I remove the daemon.json file, however dockerd start correctly, so I am guessing that, either is possible to start dockerd without providing the certificates or there are certificates somewhere that I should use to run dockerd.

How may I simply run dockerd using a daemon.json config file?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change the value of `bip` then following `daemon.json` file is sufficient.

```
{
    "bip": "172.17.42.1/16"
}
```